# Start Dartium with a flag from Dart Editor

Tags: dart, flags, dart-editor, dartium

Is it possible to start Dartium from Dart Editor with certain flag? The flag I want to use is `--enable-speech-dispatcher`. In the terminal, I pass the flag like this: `dartium --enable-speech-dispatcher`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the **Manage Launches** dialog in the **run** menu of the Dart Editor. For a Dartium launch there is a field called **Browser arguments**. Add your flags here.